# Why does ViewChildren yield no result in combination with ngComponentOutlet?

Tags: angular, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to access a child component that gets created via ngComponentOutlet but ViewChildren always returns an empty list. Is there a different approach for this?

What i tried:

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  entryComponents: [
    HomeComponent
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  pageSections = [
    HomeComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ];

  @ViewChildren(HomeComponent)
  pageSectionElems: QueryList<HomeComponent>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.pageSectionElems);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let pageSection of pageSections">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="pageSection"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using ContentChildren

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work either. Seems like the issue is already known: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842